# como puedo ampliar el rango de nextLine()?

Tags: java, scanner

```
package ejer14_22;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Morse {

String frase="";
String codigo="";
String[] palabras;


char[] uni= {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',
        '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'};

String[] morse= {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..",
        "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..",
        ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", "-----"};



public void uni(String str) {
    String translate="";
    
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<uni.length; j++) {
        
        if (String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)).equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(uni[j])))
                translate+=morse[j]+" ";
        
        }
        if(str.charAt(i)==' ' ) translate+="   ";
    }
    
    System.out.println(translate);  
}



public void split() {
    
    codigo=codigo.replaceAll("   ", " ? ");
    palabras=codigo.split("\\s");
    
    System.out.print(palabras.length);
    System.out.print("palabras");
    
    for (int j=0; j<palabras.length; j++)
        mor(palabras[j]);
}   

public void mor(String str) {
    String translate="";
    
    
        for(int j=0; j<morse.length; j++) {
        
        if (str.equals(morse[j]))
                translate+=uni[j];
                
        }
        if(str.equals("?"))  translate+=" ";
    System.out.print(translate);
    
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    Morse obj=new Morse();
    Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Que desea hacer?:\n"
            + "Traducir a morse(pulse 1): \n"
            + "Traducir a español(pulse 2): ");
    
    String choice=entrada.nextLine();
    switch (choice) {
        
    case "1": System.out.println("Introduzca la frase");

        obj.frase=entrada.nextLine();
        obj.uni(obj.frase);
        break;
    
    case "2": System.out.println("Introduzca el código");
    
        Pattern spaces=Pattern.compile("\\{4,}");
 //         entrada.useDelimiter(spaces);
        obj.codigo=entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.println (obj.codigo);
        obj.split();    
            
        break;


            
    }
}

 }
```

> Buenas tardes. El programa lo que hace es traducir una frase del español a Morse o a la inversa. Cuando traduce de español a morse, el nextline() coge todo el texto y lo traduce bien. Pero a la inversa, el nextLine() sólo coge una porción, creo que hasta un separador de línea. La verdad, no se porqué en un caso coge todo el texto y en el otro no. Como es por el nextline() he buscado formas de hacer que lea más allá pero no he logrado hacerlo. Cuando se pulsa la opción dos(traducir de morse a español), el código morse debe introducirse separando cada letra morse(por ejemplo .- .- .- que es A A A mediante un espacio y separar las palabras morse mediante 3 espacios, por ejemplo .- .- .-   .- .- .-, que seria A A A(3 espacios)A A A. Todo lo hace bien excepto leer más allá de una línea de morse... MI pregunta es ¿cómo ampliar nextline para que lea todo el código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo veo dos formas aquí de hacer lo que quieres:

La primera es leer desde un fichero en vez de la entrada, y leer todo el fichero hasta que ya no haya más letras por leer. Se leería letras en bucle hasta que se encuentre el fin de fichero (`EOF`). De manera conceptual queda así:

```
char letra;
StringBuffer textoCompleto = new StringBuffer();
while (true) {
    letra = leerDeFichero();
if (letra == EOF) break;
    textoCompleto.append(letra);
}
String traucido = traducir(textoCompleto.toString());
```

La segunda opción es la que comentas tú: leer utilizando un delimitador que sea un símbolo a tu elección, diferente del salto de línea o del retorno de carro. Así puedes leer directamente de la entrada.

Answer (score 1):

después de darle vueltas averigüé que el método next() de Scanner scanea el siguiente token y si configuras el token con el método useDelimiter​(String pattern), puedes hacer que el token sea todo lo largo que desees. En mi caso, al final del String solicito un "#" por ejemlo y me lee todo el input:

Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("#");
obj.codigo=entrada.next();